# Enable AddressSanitizer by default in gcc

Tags: gcc, fuzzing, sanitizer, address-sanitizer

To be able to debug and fuzz a whole Linux distribution, I would like to set ASAN (AddressSanitizer, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) as default option to gcc. So normally to achieve what I want, generally,  I set the following variables before to compile a linux package:

```
CFLAGS="-fsanitize=address,undefined -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Werror=array-bounds -g" 
CXXFLAGS="-fsanitize=address,undefined -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Werror=array-bounds -g" 
LDFLAGS="-fsanitize=address,undefined"
```

and try to compile and run my code. I would like to have it default to gcc.

One option to do it is using spec files: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html. However I didn't find a way to set a "catch all rules" to compile and link all my c/c++ code with AddressSanitizer.

My questions are:

- Any example how to do it using spec files?
- Is that the best approach to do it?
- Any other alternative approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, be sure to take a look at existing whole-distro Asan enablings in [Tizen](http://injoit.org/index.php/j1/article/viewFile/231/184) (also [here](https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/ASan)) and [Gentoo](https://archive.fosdem.org/2016/schedule/event/csafecode/attachments/slides/1131/export/events/attachments/csafecode/slides/1131/fosdem_gentoo_asan.pdf).

In general there are two main approaches:

- customize your build system to enable Asan by default, usually using `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`; this won't always work because many packages ignore them (I think that's what Hanno Boeck did in Gentoo)
- replace `/usr/bin/gcc`, `/usr/bin/g++` and `/usr/bin/cc` (and may `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc`, `x86_64-linux-gnu-g++`) with wrappers which would add Asan flags and redirect calls to original executables (this is the approach we eventually took in Tizen and found it very successful)

As a side note, I'd suggest to add the following options

```
CFLAGS += -fsanitize-recover=address,undefined
```

otherwise boot will fail at too early stages. Also look at suggested settings `ASAN_OPTIONS` in above links, it took people long time to figure them out.

Comment: hi, could you point me to a gcc wrapper example? I found for example https://github.com/gawen947/gcc-wrapper which I could look into, however if you have something already in mind, it would be better..

Comment: @VP. Well, it's really just a primitive shell wrapper which calls "true" gcc with `-fanitize=address -fsanitize-recover=address -fno-common etc.`. Gcc wrappers is a common practice (see e.g. [pbuilder instructions](https://wiki.debian.org/PbuilderTricks#How_to_use_pbuilder_to_test_build_with_gcc-snapshot)) but I'm afraid I don't have a link specific to Asan.

Comment: Ok, I did something like

export MYFLAGS="...";

exec /usr/bin/gcc-6 $@

but it didnt work somehow.. thank you by the great input!

Comment: @VP. FYI I just I checked the Tizen article, it has example wrapper (Fig. 5). You are welcome.